# Data from Oracle BLOB datatype column to Snowflake migration using Python script

Tags: python, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-migration

I am trying to migrate data from Oracle BLOB column to Snowflake database table using Python script.
I am able to migrate data for all other data types by creating csv by extracting data from Oracle and loading into Snowflake DB. Can anyone know how do we achieve this migration using Python script ?
Thanks.

Comment: Snowflake doesn't support BLOB, but [**BINARY**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-unsupported.html) can be used instead. And I can see that Oracle already provided a way of fetching/reading [BLOBs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html). You can use that as a start to insert that data into a BINARY on Snowflake.

Comment: If the blobs are small(ish) and you wanted to export the Oracle blob to CSV you can encode the binary data to base64 and load it as you'd normally load a csv file into Snowflake with a BINARY column and decode the base64 with sql .

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot load the data more than, max 16MB compressed or uncompressed provided by the snowflake for their data types like varchar and variant
so instead of loading blob data column into a snowflake, save it into AWS s3 , and in snowflake, blob migrated columns holds blob data address from s3 location